# Rstudio xgboost: Error in xgb.serialize(object$handle) : std::bad_alloc

Tags: r, serialization, xgboost

I'm getting the following error after finishing the nrounds (or reaching early stopping) on xgboost: Error in xgb.serialize(object$handle) : std::bad_alloc

Google has been no help so far, and I've tried rebooting my machine, clearing all memory before running the xgboost etc. Still running in the same error, only once I didn't run into this error but I've no clue why it didn't.

The machine I'm working on has 48gb RAM, so it shouldn't be a problem in that area.

The xgboost is running on 66.764 rows with 36 variables, running a tree-depth of 20 with a learning rate of 10/nrounds & nrounds of 35.000 usually reaching the early stopping point (not improving for 100 rounds) at around 22.000-23.000.

```
  params = list(
  max_depth = 20,
  eta = 10/ntrees,
  gamma = 1,
  colsample_bytree = 1,
  min_child_weight = 1,
  subsample = 1,
  objective = "reg:squarederror")

Output <- xgboost(data = dtrain,
                                   params = params,
                                   nrounds = ntrees,
                                   early_stopping_rounds = 100,
                                   print_every_n = 250,
                                   verbose = 1
)
```

Comment: On linux, I run `htop` in a terminal while running `R` in another as it provides pretty close to real-time view of Ram, Swap, and CPU. 48G sounds huge to someone with 8, `> 66746 * 36 * 20 * 10
[1] 480571200` could be a big number or not (here assuming learning rate is related to how much is held in memory - likely wrong on this) but `htop` will clarify use of resources and perhaps eliminate that  as area of concern for debugging this. There must be an equivalent tool available for Windows.

Comment: And of course it's more complicated than I naively proposed [bad_alloc is not out-of-memory](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1404r1.html), but as often as not, out of swap and crash.

Comment: I'm seeing it try to allocate as we speak right now and pushing the RAM to the absolute edge. Currently using 42gb of RAM in RStudio, so definitely an option that the RAM is the cause here. But that's not something I'm going to be able to solve, you'd say 48gb of RAM should be more than enough. I can't find any settings in xgboost itself to "fix" this bleeding of RAM though... I've downgraded from R4.1 to R4.05 since the latest release of xgboost wasn't built for R4.1 which I hope will solve it.

Comment: R-4.0.5 released 2021-03-31, xgboost-1.4.1.1 was released 2021-4-22, and is running on my R-4.1.0 2021-05-18, Ub 20.04.1 LTS. Since it takes some day(s) to rebuild all pkgs, I'd hate to downgrade, but don't think was necessary in this case. Pretty sure xgboost was released with 4.1.0 in mind as there's close coordination at that devel level about breaking changes. How goes?

Comment: What makes you say 'bleeding of Ram'? btw.

Comment: Read these eight messages on [r-devel](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2021-June/080809.html) discussing dgRMatrix, but ending at `Matrix` and perhaps re-install your Matrix pkg from r-forge src, as I assume they have fixed...

Comment: Fixed when reported, due to good report.